# How can i setting Ghidra like ida pro?

Tags: c++, ida, ghidra

I'm using Ghidra. I have something question.
when i open binary IDA pro, The code was very good to analyze.
This is IDA pro Decompile code

```
printf("Tell me something about yourself: ");
  fgets(&s, 32, edata);
  std::string::operator=(&input, &s);
  std::allocator<char>::allocator(&v5);
  std::string::string((int)&v4, (int)"you", (int)&v5);
  std::allocator<char>::allocator(&v7);
  std::string::string((int)&v6, (int)"I", (int)&v7);
  replace((std::string *)&v3);
```

and this is Ghidra Same part.

```
  printf("Tell me something about yourself: ");
  fgets(local_40,0x20,stdin);
  operator=((basic_string<char,std--char_traits<char>,std--allocator<char>> *)&input,local_40);
  allocator();
  basic_string((char *)local_1c,(allocator *)&DAT_08049823);
  allocator();
  basic_string((char *)local_14,(allocator *)&DAT_08049827);
  replace(local_20,&input,local_14,local_1c);
  operator=((basic_string<char,std--char_traits<char>,std--allocator<char>> *)&input,
            (basic_string *)local_20);
```

The question is when i open binary with IDA Pro, they can show me string. like

```
std::string::string((int)&v4, (int)"you", (int)&v5); 
std::string::string((int)&v6, (int)"I", (int)&v7);
```

but in Ghidra

```
  basic_string((char *)local_1c,(allocator *)&DAT_08049823);
  allocator();
  basic_string((char *)local_14,(allocator *)&DAT_08049827);
```

I just want to know how can i change configuration in ghidra.
Like this

```
local_1c -> "you" , local_14 -> "I"
```